# Mariadb index generated by foreign key creation not "working"

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, foreign-keys

I use a mariadb 10.3.27 with innodb engine mostly standard configuration.

We create a foreign key that induce creating index.
All seams fine but the index is not use in a simple left join on the fk on complex query
[image]

And *show index from* give a cardinality of **2** for this index. So I optimize the table but nothing change.

I create an index on that column with another name, there is no warning (but there is already an index on that column) and it override existing index.
The cardinality become **154** and execution plan become correct :
[image]

Maybe a bug ? Or I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Clever technique!  Maybe if we could see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`, we could say more.

Comment: The point is not the table neither the query but the comportement of the index. I fact this is during a data migration, so maybe that's index statistique / execution plan that is not update with new data. And we did the migration with success.